# Telethon not reconnect

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Running with the first code creates a session file and runs it. use this file to run the second code, the session will not work.

**First code**

```
import telethon
from telethon import tl
from telethon import TelegramClient
import logging

def update_handler(update_object):
    print(update_object)
phone_number='*'
client = telethon.TelegramClient('sweet',api_id = *,api_hash = '*')
client.connect()
print('connected')
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))
print(client.get_me())
print(me.stringify())
```

Output:

connected

Enter code: 85813

User(is_self=True,contact=True,mutual_contact=False,deleted=False,bot=False,bot_chat_history=False,bot_nochats=False,verified=False,restricted=False,min=False,bot_inline_geo=False,id=*,access_hash=-*,first_name='-',last_name=None,username=None,phone=‘*’,photo=None,status=UserStatusOnline(expires=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1515302772)), bot_info_version=None, restriction_reason=None, bot_inline_placeholder=None, lang_code=None)

User(is_self=True,contact=True,mutual_contact=False,deleted=False,bot=False,bot_chat_history=False,bot_nochats=False,verified=False,restricted=False,min=False,bot_inline_geo=False,id=*,access_hash=-*,first_name='-',last_name=None,username=None,phone=‘*’,photo=None,status=UserStatusOnline(expires=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1515302772)), bot_info_version=None, restriction_reason=None, bot_inline_placeholder=None, lang_code=None)

**Second code**

```
import telethon
from telethon import tl
from telethon import TelegramClient
import logging

def update_handler(update_object):
    print(update_object)
phone_number='**'
client = telethon.TelegramClient('sweet',api_id = *,api_hash = '*')
client.connect()
print('connected')
print(client.get_me())
```

Output:

```
None
```